# シェルスクリプトで実行中のプログラムに入力する方法

Tags: linux

シェルスクリプトでコマンドライン上で行う入力はできるのですが、実行プログラムに対して入力することができません。

例えば、c言語のscanfなどがあるプログラムを実行するときのscanfへの入力もシェルスクリプト上で行いたいのですが、そのような場合はどうしたら良いのでしょうか

シェルスクリプト上で実行プログラムに入力をする記述法を教えて下さい

---

追記
入力もシェルスクリプト内で自動化したいという意味です。
現在使用しているプログラムでは多数の入力ファイルをひとつずつ読み込んで、こちらから文字列を入力します。
しかし、読み込みにかかる時間が長いため、入力ファイルを読み込んだ後の文字列の手入力も自動化すれば、効率が良くなると考えています。

毎回手入力する文字列は同じなのですが、文字列の数が100個近くあるのでしんどいです。
対話型の入力です。

Comment: 何もしなくてもシェルスクリプトから起動されたプログラムは親から標準入力を引き継ぐのでターミナルから入力できるはずです。プログラムに自動的に入力を行いたいとうことですか?

Comment: 自動入力を行いたいということです。

Comment: `scanf` で読み込んでいて入力が固定なら
`echo "your input" > your_command`
のようにリダイレクトを使えば解決する気がします。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

対話型のコマンドをシェルスクリプトで実行したいということですよね？
`expect`コマンドを使ってください。

例としてログインをシェルスクリプト化します。

```
set timeout 10 #タイムアウトの秒数
spawn slogin user@host # 実行コマンド
expect "Password :" # 期待する表示される文字列
send "password\r" # 入力
```

`expect`にはワイルドカード、正規表現が使用できます。

Answer (score 3):

実行プログラムへの入力もスクリプト内で自動化したい、ということでしょうか？

混みいった受け答えがないのであれば、ヒアドキュメントを使うのはどうでしょう？

```
コマンド << END_OF_INPUT
*入力*
*入力*
*入力*
END_OF_INPUT
```

の形で、入力をスクリプト内にわかりやすく記載できます。(`END_OF_INPUT` は対応していればなんでも構いません)

例えば、

```
$ mysql -u root -p << END_OF_INPUT
use information_schema;
show TABLES;
select TABLE_NAME from TABLES;
END_OF_INPUT
```

なんて使い方ができます。